# Extracting key values across nested JSON

Tags: json, jquery

I am trying to extract the values from a nested JSON file that looks like so:

```
var mymenu = {"menu": [{"page": {"url": "http://foo.bar.com","random stuff": {"junk": "rubbish"}}},{"page": {"feed": "http://foo.bar.com"}},{"menu": [{"submenu": [{"page": {"feed": "http://foo.bar.com"}}]}]}]};
```

The keys I am trying to extract are the feeds with contain urls. I have tried a for...in loop into the retrieved JSON but I can only get as far as pulling the object that the feed is in resulting in the stringified object as a whole. Is there a way to get just the keys I need from the JSON file?

Comment: Is `var` a valid variable name?

Comment: Fixed the variable.
@felix - I could not find that thread at all before hand it looks like that could be help I needed

Answer (score 0):

I just validated your json on [`JSONLint`](http://jsonlint.com/) and it seems to be invalid.

```
Parse error on line 7:
...                   }            }    
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING'
```

Try this json, and remember to assign a `name` to your variable.

```
var mymenu = {"menu": [{"page": {"url": "http://foo.bar.com","random stuff": {"junk": "rubbish"}}},{"page": {"feed": "http://foo.bar.com"}},{"menu": [{"submenu": [{"page": {"feed": "http://foo.bar.com"}}]}]}]};
```

Next iterating through the json isn't too bad, just think of it as a `multi dimensional` array with `key value` pairs. For instance, if you're running firefox it's a good idea to get [`firebug`](http://getfirebug.com/).

```
for(var i = 0; i < mymenu['menu'].length; i)
{
    console.log(mymenu['menu'][i]);
}
```

Comment: My bad on the pasted JSON was trying to rework an example to show.